# GMail API pagination use of nextPageToken

Tags: jquery, pagination, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Have spent hours searching Google et. al. for an answer, sure it's simple but how do you create pagination with the GMail api using nextPageToken?  what ever I do cannot get pagination to work (back and forth that is).

Assume 'authorised user' and access with the right scopes I call

```
 gapi.client.load('gmail','v1',displayInbox);
```

then

```
function displayInbox(){
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId':'me',
    'maxResults':10,
    });

  request.execute(function(response){
    $.each(response.messages,function(){
      var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
        'userId':'me',
        'id':this.id
      });
      messageRequest.execute(appendMessageRow);
    });
  });
}
```

appendMessageRow simply lays out the list in a table e.g.

```
function appendMessageRow(message){
   var txt = '<tr>';
   txt +='<td>'+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From')+'</td>';
   txt +='<td>';
   txt +='<a href="#message-modal-'+ message.id +'" data-toggle="modal" id="message-link-' + message.id+'">' +getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +'</a>';
   txt +='</td>';
   txt +='<td class="text-xs-right">'+moment(parseInt(message.internalDate)).format('HH:mm')+'</td>';
   txt +='</tr>';
   $('table tbody').append(txt);
}
```

When I console.log request.execute I see nextPageToken as an object key  What I cannot do and need to do is add pagination buttons - messageRequest.execute does not pass the nextPageToken plus there does not seem to be a way to create/obtain a 'previousPageToken'.

Sorry if simple but is it me or is there far more to it than that?  The GMail API docs appear very poor (to me) on this subject and I have not found a stackoverflow answer that helps.

To recap - how do I add pagination buttons and pass the appropriate variables to call/recall displayInbox().

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could save the next page token on every request and use it in your next request. If there is no next page token in the response, you know that you have gotten all messages:

```
function listMessages(pageToken) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var options = {
      userId: 'me',
      maxResults: 10
    };
    if (pageToken) {
      options.pageToken = pageToken;
    }
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list(options);
    request.execute(resolve);
  });
}

function getMessage(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
      userId: 'me',
      id: message.id
    });
    messageRequest.execute(resolve);
  });
}

var pageToken;
function displayInbox(){
  listMessages(pageToken).then(function (response) {
    if (response.nextPageToken) {
      pageToken = response.nextPageToken; // Get the next page next time
    } else {
      console.log('No more pages left!');
    }
    if (response.messages) {
      Promise.all(response.messages.map(getMessage)).then(function (messages) {
        messages.forEach(appendMessageRow);
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Tholle - got that TY pagination goes 'forward' - NP but not sure where - at which point to access the 'old' nextPageToken before it gets updated - sorry if sound thick (well I am :)).  I can get the  'old & new' tokens in console.log inside displayInbox() but I cannot get them (or any saved data) to send the list back i.e. the 'old/last' token  The new token always overrides it any clues please?

Comment: @RussellParrott You can't paginate backwards in the API, I'm afraid. You could store each page from the API when you page forwards, and just insert the old page again when you go backwards without calling the API.

Comment: Tholle - I got the You can't paginate backwards in the API before - strange as it's called 'pagination' suppose that's MrG. OK spent time trying to get the right place to grab the variables to 'store' but to no avail, could you please add 2 //lines to your example as the best place to save them/call them - I use firebase so updating is quick & simple. Many many thanks –