# Using Google Apps Script, how do you remove built in Gmail category labels from an email?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, typeerror

I'd like to completely undo any of Gmails built in category labels. This was my attempt.

```js
function removeBuiltInLabels() {
  var updatesLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("updates");
  var socialLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("social");
  var forumsLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("forums");
  var promotionsLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("promotions");

  var inboxThreads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox');
  for (var i = 0; i < inboxThreads.length; i++) {
    updatesLabel.removeFromThreads(inboxThreads[i]);
    socialLabel.removeFromThreads(inboxThreads[i]);
    forumsLabel.removeFromThreads(inboxThreads[i]);
    promotionsLabel.removeFromThreads(inboxThreads[i]);
  }

}
```

However, this throws....

> TypeError: Cannot call method "removeFromThreads" of null.

It seems you can't access the built in labels in this way even though you can successfully search for `label:updates` in the Gmail search box and get the correct results.

The question...

**How do you access the built in Gmail Category labels in Google Apps Script and remove them from an email/thread/threads?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'INBOX' and other system labels like 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL' can be removed using Advanced Gmail Service. In the Script Editor, go to Resources -> Advanced Google services and enable the Gmail service.
More details about naming conventions for system labels in Gmail can be found here [Gmail API - Managing Labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels)

Retrieve the threads labeled with 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL' by calling the list() method of the threads collection:

```
 var threads = Gmail.Users.Threads.list("me", {labels: ["CATEGORY_SOCIAL"]});
 var threads = threads.threads;
 var nextPageToken  = threads.nextPageToken;
```

Note that you are going to need to store the 'nextPageToken' to iterate over the entire collection of threads. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761245/gmail-api-pagination-use-of-nextpagetoken).
When you get all thread ids, you can call the 'modify()' method of the Threads collection on them:

```
 threads.forEach(function(thread){
         var resource = {
        "addLabelIds": [],
        "removeLabelIds":["CATEGORY_SOCIAL"]
      };
      Gmail.Users.Threads.modify(resource, "me", threadId);
});
```

If you have lots of threads in your inbox, you may still need to call the 'modify()' method several times and save state between calls.

Comment: I wonder if one could do a similar process with threads which might take less time perhaps.

Comment: @Cooper you can call var threads =  GmailApp.search("in: social") and retrieve all message ids

Comment: @Cooper Good point. I overlooked the fact that Gmail API has a thread class too

Comment: Thanks! Led directly to my version below. 

Answer (score 0):

Anton's answer is great. I marked it as accepted because it lead directly to the version I'm using.

This function lets you define any valid gmail search to isolate messages and enables batch removal labels.

```js
function removeLabelsFromMessages(query, labelsToRemove) {
  var foundThreads = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {'q': query}).threads
  if (foundThreads) {
    foundThreads.forEach(function (thread) {
      Gmail.Users.Threads.modify({removeLabelIds: labelsToRemove}, 'me', thread.id);
    });
  }
}
```

I call it via the one minute script trigger like this.

```js
function ProcessInbox() {
  removeLabelsFromMessages(
    'label:updates OR label:social OR label:forums OR label:promotions',
    ['CATEGORY_UPDATES', 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL', 'CATEGORY_FORUMS', 'CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS']
  )

  <...other_stuff_to_process...>
}
```