# How to remove user Labels from Gmail using GScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

In relation to another question that removes [Category Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256569/using-google-apps-script-how-do-you-remove-built-in-gmail-category-labels-from/68075736#68075736), I'd like to use the same code and simply add other user labels to the routines created.

The routines are as follows:

```
function removeLabelsFromMessages(query, labelsToRemove) {
  var foundThreads = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {'q': query}).threads
  if (foundThreads) {
    foundThreads.forEach(function (thread) {
      Gmail.Users.Threads.modify({removeLabelIds: labelsToRemove}, 'me', thread.id);
    });
  }
}

function ProcessInbox() {
  removeLabelsFromMessages(
    'label:updates OR label:social OR label:forums OR label:promotions',
    ['CATEGORY_UPDATES', 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL', 'CATEGORY_FORUMS', 'CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS']
  )

  <...other_stuff_to_process...>
}
```

I'm wondering if you can add another user label to the "labelsToRemove" - I've tried simply adding another label to the array, but keep getting an error stating the label cannot be found. I'm' sure it's just a syntax error (I don't code very much), so any suggestions on how to add that?

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
function CleanReceipts () {
  removeLabel (
    'label: Receipts', 
    ['CATEGORY_UPDATES', 'CATEGORY_SOCIAL', 'CATEGORY_FORUMS', 'CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS', '@SaneLater']
  )
}
```

where "@SaneLater" is the name of a user label I'd like to remove as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `Label not found error` is because the `threads.modify` method is expecting a *label id* and not *a label name*.

In order to retrieve the id of this specific label, I suggest you take a look at [`labels.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list) and make the request to get the appropriate value:

```
let labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
console.log(labels);
```

#### Reference

- [Gmail API users.threads.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/modify).