# GMAIL API Page token informations

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm creating an prgram that need to request a large amount of email.
But I'm wondering what is the next page token if there is no more mails available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [GMail API pagination use of nextPageToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761245/gmail-api-pagination-use-of-nextpagetoken), but it's really only covered by that question and not entirely the same.

Anyway, there won't be a `nextPageToken` if you've gotten all the messages. Alternatively, you could also use `resultSizeEstimate` and compare with your total retrieved messages to check if you have more mail to get.

Answer (score 1):

The google .net client library has a method called PageStreamer which handles all the next pageing for you.  You shouldnt need to worry about the next page token.

```
var pageStreamer = new PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message, MessagesResource.ListRequest, MessageList, string>(
                                                   (request, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                                   response => response.NextPageToken,
                                                   response => response.Items);
           
var req = service.Messages.List();
req.MaxResults = 1000;

foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(req))
  {
  Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
  }
```